# Bash-script, sed with two variables doesn't work

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script which change IP address every once in a while but for some reason I just can't get this working

`sed "s/$curLine/$nextLine/" </etc/network/interfaces>/etc/network/interfaces.new`, even if I change the end /g, I will always get "sed unterminated `s' command"

Here is my variables $curLine and $nextLine:

```
#Find current ip from /etc/network/interfaces

    curLine=$(sed -n "/address/p" /etc/network/interfaces)

#Find location of current ip in ips.txt.

    newLine=$(sed -n "/$curLine/=" ips.txt)

#Check and set next ip

    nextIP=$(($newLine+1))

    nextLine=$(sed -n "$nextIP,/address/p" ./ips.txt)
```

for some reason $nextLine also gives me two ips I don't know why because at the beginning ot worked just fine.

and in the end this is the line which doesn't work as it should.

```
"s/$curLine/$nextLine/" </etc/network/interfaces>/etc/network/interfaces.new
```

error message "sed unterminated `s' command". If I replace $nextline with text like "address xxx.xxx.xxx.xx it works just fine.

I have read so many topics where solution was use double quotes but I don't know why it doesn't work with me. I also have a book where's an example which is basically just same what I'm doing but again it doesn't work when I try use it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just changed

```
nextLine=$(sed -n "$nextIP,/address/p" ./ips.txt)
```

to search range of lines instead of specific line with a pattern.

```
nextLine=$(sed -n "$nextIP,/$nextIP" ./ips.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for arithmetic has no extra sigil:

```
NUM=1
OTHERNUM=$((NUM + 1))
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In other words, say `nextIP=$((newLine+1))`.

Comment: I'm not sure did I get what you mean. Now I changed


`nextIP=$((newLine+1))` and



`nextLine=$(sed -n "$nextIP,/address/p" ips.txt)`

but still for some reason I got two ip:s after following:


`echo 'Next line '$nextLine`

and again "unterminated `s' command"

Comment: Are you sure you can pass `$curLine` into the `sed` command without any escaping? Have you tried this manually on the command line first?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, at least when I echo out $curLine it gives me an IP from interfaces and it's right as " address xxx.x.xx.xxx. my ips.txt also include ips formated as "address xxx..." and I'm trying to replace interfaces address line with ips.txt address line.

Comment: What about echoing `$newLine`?

Comment: $newLine says current ip position in ips.txt is line 1 and that's correct.

Then my $nextIP says "nextIP position to be used: 2" which means line2 in ips.txt. After that for some reason $nextLine gives me two addresses "address xxx... address yyy..."

I've assumed "sed -n "$nextIP,/address/p" ./ips.txt" should pick first address xxx.. at line $nextIP right ?